# What is difference between release notes and changelog?

Tags: version-control, release, release-management, software-distribution

Software packages are often shipped with **changelog** and/or **release notes**. What's the difference between them? Should they be both included with release of a new version?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To directly answer your question, you can include both in your software release.

[Release notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_notes) are a set of documents delivered to customers with the intent to provide a verbose description of the release of a new version of a product or service. These artifacts are generally created by a marketing team or product owner and contain feature summaries, bug fixes, use cases, and other support material. The release notes are used as a quick guide to what changed outside of the user documentation.

Conversely, [changelogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changelog) are comprehensive lists of the new features, enhancements, bugs, and other changes in reverse chronological order. Changelogs usually link to specific issues or feature requests within a change management system and also may include links to the developer who supplied the change.

Answer (score 6):

Yes I think you can include both on a new release.

For me the main difference is that in a release note you can explain what is new or what have changed in a more comprehensive language.

In the case of a changelog you have to add more technical details of the changes, for example with commit messages with link to the diff or PRs with links to the technical discussion.